# A dynamic condition for an `has_many : through` Record Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to set an `has_many : through` dynamic condition.

In my model file I have:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_category_relationships,
    :class_name  => 'Article::Categories::ArticleRelationship',
    :foreign_key => 'article_id',
    :autosave    => true,
    :dependent   => :destroy
    # Here should be the dynamic condition statement (read below for more 
    # information about this)

  has_many :article_categories,
    :through     => :article_category_relationships,
    :source      => :article_category,
    :dependent   => :destroy
end
```

In the related `Article::Categories::ArticleRelationship` database table I have also a `created_by_user_id` column (other columns are `article_id` and `category_id`) which represents the `id` of the user who created the relationship.

So, in order to retrieve article categories related to a user, in the above Record Association code I would like to filter `:article_category_relationships` by passing a dynamic condition which depends by that user `id` value. Otherwise, if I pass no `id` value, a default value should permit to retrieve all article categories by using the `@article.article_categories` code.

**Is it possible? If so, how can I code that in the Record Association statement?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a *scope* in your **category** model might be what you're looking for — something like this:

```
scope :by_user, lambda {|user|
    unless user.nil?
        where('article_category_relationships.created_by_user_id IS ?', user.id).
        join(:article_category_relationships)
    end
}
```

This allows you to call `@article.article_categories.by_user(@user)`.

Comment: Is it a common practice to put the 'article_category_relationships' table name directly in the model file?

Comment: Hmm, sorry — not sure if I understand what you mean? Could you explain?

Comment: I mean: I have seen few times to put  a name of a database table directly inside a class\model code (for me, I am a newbie, it sounds strange...); to do that is a common practice? that is, is that approach commonly used?

Comment: Are you referring to the `article_category_relationships. created_by_user_id`? — You will need to reference the associations anyway (by name) in your model and while it would be better to have 0 SQL in there, you won't be able to do that (at least to my knowledge) without using a helper such as e.g. **metawhere** in this case.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to 'article_category_relationships.created_by_user_id', more precisely to 'article_category_relationships'.